# Display different types of file with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, flask

I have a application based on Flask (Python) and AngularJS and I want to display some files on the browser, it will be reports from different security tools, which can be of different types : txt, xml, json, html...

Here is the part of my html code where the user need to click to get the file :

```
<a ng-click="getFile(scan.id, file_id)">Some text...</a>
```

Here is the code for Flask :

```
@app.route("/api/scan/<scan_id>/file/<file_id>")
def api_scan_file(scan_id, file_id):
    r = requests.get(config['backend-api']['url'] + "/scans/" + scan_id + "/file/" + file_id)
    return flask.Response(r)
```

I get the file from a backend server.

And here is the actual part of code for the AngularJS part

```
$scope.getFile = function(scanId, fileId) {
    window.open('/api/scan/' + scanId + '/file/' + fileId);
}
```

It works well for html files but not for other types... I understand why, because this is used to call an URL and not a xml file for example.

My problem is that I do not know how to properly format the file to display it on the browser.

Any help would be appreciated. If I am not clear in my explanations, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the mimetype of the response like described here : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#response-objects.

So you have to do that:

```
@app.route("/api/scan/<scan_id>/file/<file_id>")
def api_scan_file(scan_id, file_id):
    r = requests.get(config['backend-api']['url'] + "/scans/" + scan_id + "/file/" + file_id)
    return flask.Response(response=r, mimetype=r.headers['content-type'])
```

Comment: It was so easy ... How did I miss that ? Thank you very much !